# Changing Date to Next/Previous by clicking on buttons in javascript 3 value

Tags: javascript, date

xample : <  2/7/2020   3/7/2020   4/7/2020  >
I need to click the button Next or Previous to have all 3 values ​​changed at the same time.

My code

```
     if (!Date.now) {
        Date.now = function() {
       return new Date().getTime();
        }
     }
     var theDate = Date.now();

     document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)

     document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener("click", function() {
      theDate -= 86400000;
     document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)
   })
     document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", function() {
    theDate += 86400000;
      document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)
  })

     function getTheDate(getDate) {
       var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
           "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
      ];
        var months = ["January", "February", "March",
         "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
         "September", "October", "November", "December"
      ];
         var theCDate = new Date(getDate);
          return days[theCDate.getDay()] + ', ' + theCDate.getDate() + '-' + 
         months[theCDate.getMonth()] + '-' + theCDate.getFullYear();
      }
```

Views

```
     <button id="prev"><</button>
      <span id="date" style="margin:0px 30px;"></span>
     <button id="next">></button>
```

Comment: Date.now was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ed. 6), it's extremely unlikely any implementation in current use doesn't have it. There's no benefit to using it in place of just `new Date()` in the OP anyway, it's even exactly the same number of characters. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Date()` will return a Date object set the current date. To get yesterday and tomorrow, simply add or subtract a day

```
let today = new Date();
let yesterday = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
let tomorrow =  today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
```

in your click handler, just update `today` in the desired direction and update the other values.

you don't need to write your own function to format date strings, just use `DateTimeFormat`. This is already localized and can take different timezones into account.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts

```
let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {   weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric'})
```

will return `Friday, 7/3/2020`